# using JOIN two table but data did not display

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `JOIN` to join two tables:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee JOIN employee_medical on employee = medical_notes";
   $data = mysql_query($sql , $testing);
```

and I display the table and the data:

```
   echo "<table border=2>
    <tr>
   <th>emp_id</th>
   <th>emp_name</th>
   <th>emp_ic</th>
   <th>emp_phone</th>
   <th>emp_address</th>
   <th>medical_notes</th>
   </tr>";


if($data = mysql_query($sql) or die ())
  {

while ( $record = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{

    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['emp_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['emp_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['emp_ic'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['emp_phone'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['emp_address']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['medical_notes']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

};

Is there a problem in my PHP coding?  My table is displayed but the data is not.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($data)`? Is there data in there in the  first place? This will help determine if the error is in the MySQL part or the PHP part.

Comment: Without seeing your DB, just based on the names in your join (employee = medical_notes), it sounds like you're not joining on valid data. Of course this depends on your table structures. I would expect something like JOIN ... ON employee.id = employee_medical.emp_id.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is any `PHP` related issue present but your query `ON` clause is weird. It should rather look like

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM employee e 
//Provide proper column names on which to join both the table 
JOIN employee_medical em on e.employeeid = em.medical_notes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixes and solutions:

- Use `die(":: ".mysql_error($testing));` To output any SQL errors.
- `$data = mysql_query($sql) or die(":: ".mysql_error() ));`
- You need to define the `<table>.<columns>` in MySQL when you are referencing more than one table, for every single column referenced, Rahul has the correct answer. 
  So:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee JOIN employee_medical on employee.employee = employee_medical.medical_notes";`

See the `<Table>.<column>` structure? Always use that.

- It is very good idea to get into the habit if declaring which type of `JOIN` you want to use. There are INNER, OUTER and some other Joins, please explore and clarify your code.
- Update to ***MySQLi***, with your reference already to the connection with `$testing` you are nearly there! Turn all your `MySQL_` commands to `mysqli_<whatever>($connection, $querty);` (it's a little more complex, but only a little.
- `mysql_fetch_array` *might* not return key values, depending on how your SQL  is set up. so if the data does not appear but you're **SURE** it's there, then try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead.